Migration from ElaticSearch to OpenSearch Error Must Clause
let query;

    const { startDate, endDate } = calculateTimeRange(time);
    let mustClauses : any = []; 
    let mustNot : any = [];
      if(startDate && endDate){
        mustClauses = {
          "must" : {
            "range" : {
              "offense_start_time" : {
                "gte" : startDate,
                "lte" : endDate
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if(type !== "ALL"){
        mustClauses.push({
          "term" : {
            "source_siem.keyword" : type
          }
        })
      }
      if(telco_type !=="ALL"){
          if(telco_type=="telco"){
              mustNot = {
                "must_not" : {
                  "term" : {
                    "telco_name.keyword": this.configService.get("LOCAL_TELCO")
                  }
                }
              }
          }else{
            mustClauses.push({
              "term" : {
                "telco_name.keyword" : telco_type
              }
            })
          }
      }
    if (select_records_by_type == "0" || select_records_by_type == "ALL" || select_records_by_type == 0) {
      query = {
        "track_total_hits" : true,
        "size": 0,
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": mustClauses,
            "must_not": mustNot || []
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "group_by_<base_column>": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "<base_column>.keyword",
              "size": 10000
            }
          }
        }
      };

This was the SQL query I was doing in Elastic search and it was working fine.
query = `SELECT ${base_column}, count(*) as frequency
      //          FROM ${this.configService.get("ALERT_INDEX")}
      //          WHERE ${type !== "ALL" ? `source_siem='${type}'` : "1=1"}
      //          AND ${
      //             startDate != undefined && endDate != undefined
      //             ? `offense_start_time >= ${startDate} AND offense_start_time < ${endDate}`
      //             : "1=1"
      //           } 
      //          AND ${telco_type !== "ALL" ? (telco_type == "telco" ? `telco_name !='${this.configService.get("LOCAL_TELCO")}'` : `telco_name='${telco_type}'`) : "1=1"}
      //          GROUP BY ${base_column}`;

I am trying to convert a SQL query which my teammate was doing for fetching data from ElasticSearch.Now I am being tasked to migrate from Elastic Search to Open Search.Now I am getting following error when I hit API from my ReactJS frontend to my NestJS backend.I have attached the SQL code as well and this is the error I am getting when I hit the API.Although on my console I am getting the query printed , but the response timeout occurs because of my query problem.
{
    "message": "x_content_parse_exception: [parsing_exception] Reason: unknown query [must]",
    "data": {}
}

This is the response I am getting on the console.
-------------------I am in the offence service-----------------------
-----------------------I am in the new conversion---------------------------------
{ must: { range: { offense_start_time: [Object] } } }
query in here
{
  track_total_hits: true,
  size: 0,
  query: { bool: { must: [Object], must_not: [] } },
  aggs: { 'group_by_<base_column>': { terms: [Object] } }
}



In this block your mustClauses start with a must
if(startDate && endDate){
        mustClauses = {
          "must" : {
            "range" : {
              "offense_start_time" : {
                "gte" : startDate,
                "lte" : endDate
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

Your final query will be
query: { bool: { must:"must":{...} , must_not: [] } }

the must query don't support another must instead you can use bool query and use the must inside the bool like this
{"must":[{"bool":{"must":[....]}]}


The rest of the query is good to go like adding the terms in must and other parts of the query.Becasue after fixing what you pointed out I am still getting errors.
